# Convergence of divergence of piecewise series

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have the series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{b_k}$$ , where
$$b_k = \begin{cases}
k^2 & 1\leq k \leq 8 \\
0 & k > 8 \end{cases}$$.

I am trying to find if the series converges or diverges. By inspecting the partial sums I find a formula for the nth partial sum as the one below :

$$S_n = \begin{cases}
\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} & 1\leq k \leq 8 \\
204 & k > 8 \end{cases}$$.

So, im concluding that the series converges to 204.

But I am confused with the fact that for the sequence $b_k$ the $liminfb_k$ and $limsupb_k$ are not equal thus the sequence $b_k$ is not convergent. So, how can the limit of its nth partial sum converge?

Can someone clarify this because I think I am making some wrong correlations.

Comment: I was just wondering if there is a correlation between the original sequence and its nth partial sum sequence but as you pointed out there is not

Comment: The [Test for Divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test) gives the only dependable correlation (which in this context is more easily seen in its [contrapositive form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test#Proofs)). Remember that the convergence of an infinite series is, by definition, exactly the same as the convergence of its sequence of partial sums.

Comment: the $liminfb_k$ and $limsupb_k$ are not equal so it cannot converge. Also not every subsequence converges to the same number so the sequence cannot converge.

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti you're right, I deleted my other comment since it was incorrect.

Comment: @Gaussbaby $\liminf_{n\to\infty}b_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\inf_{m\geq n}b_m)=0.$ You seem to have misunderstood, what the limit inferior of an infinite sequence is.

Comment: @MathR I was confused with the limsup but i can see now it is 0 as well.